# How can you override .testcaferc.json browsers in CLI

Tags: javascript, docker, command-line-interface, testcafe

**Context:**

I have a situation where I want to run Testcafe in docker in a remote environment which requires Testcafe to be run through its CLI, I want to use the .testcaferc file that I also use to test locally so I don't have to manage 2 sets of config. But need to override specific properties to get it working in this environment.

Notably `chrome` locally and `chromium:headless` in the pipeline.

**The problem:**

I can't figure out how to override the browsers for the CLI tool - I can override every other key just fine, but the browser to run on doesn't get overridden

**Example CLI command:**

```
testcafe \
            chromium:headless \
            --ports 1337,1338  \
            --disable-gpu-sandbox \
            --disable-gpu \
            --no-sandbox \
            --disable-dev-shm-usage \
            ...
```

**Example .testcaferc.json:**

```
{
   "browsers": ["chrome"],
   ...
}
```

**Expected:**

Runs only `chromium:headless`

**Actual:**

Fails trying to run `chrome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6618
We have fixed it in the latest TestCafe release: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe/v/1.19.0

Please update to v1.19.0.